# Id is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to add related data to my database with Entity Framework Core. I have an Identity database with my users and in this database I have a next tables :
**AspNetUsers** and **Expenses**. I tried to do it, but instead of good result I get an exception

[image]

User model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 20,ErrorMessage = "{0} length must be between {2} and {1}.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 20, ErrorMessage = "{0} length must be between {2} and {1}.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get => string.Format($"{FirstName} {LastName}"); }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime birthDay { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public float Money { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; } = new List<Expense>();
}
```

Expense model:

```
public class Expense
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Context Database:

```
 public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<User, AppRole, Guid>
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Expenses.Models.Expense> UserExpenses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Expenses)
            .WithOne(u => u.User)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserId);

            builder.Entity<Expense>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

View for creating expense:

```
    @model Expenses.ViewModels.ExpenseViewModel

<div class="crud-container">
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title"></label>
            <input asp-for="Title"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="error-validation"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
             <label asp-for="Price"></label>
            <input asp-for="Price"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="error-validation"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the last part of code is **Create** method in my **ExpenseController**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ExpenseViewModel model)
    {
        User user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        Expense expense = new Expense()
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Price = model.Price,
        };

        user.Expenses.Add(expense);
        
        userContext.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This is a very common error. First attach `user` to `userContext` or only set `expense.UserId`.

Comment: Since you're using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` you need to specify a value for `Expense.Id` yourself. Because you're not doing that right now `Id` is always 0, but `Id` needs to be unique

Comment: @GertArnold can you give me an example? I don't what does attach mean  in this context.